# Eigen openmp support on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: c++, ubuntu, openmp, eigen

I get an ugly linker error related to `openmp` (undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads_`,  `omp_get_num_threads_` etc) when trying to build a code that includes `Eigen 3.2` matrix library headers using `g++ 4.8.2`. The target OS is `Ubuntu 14.04`. I am using `-fopenmp` when compiling and also tried linking with `-lgomp`, still same linker error. The program links just fine under `Debian 7`, `OS X Mavericks` and `Solaris 11`. Is there a problem with `Eigen` support for `openmp` under `Ubuntu 14.04`? It is the only OS under which I get this linker error.

The `Ubuntu 14.04` `g++-4.8` compiler links simple `openmp` programs (with `#pragma`'s inside) just fine, such as a `#pragma omp parallel for`, the problem appears when trying to compile and link something that includes `Eigen`...

Thanks!

Comment: `omp_get_max_threads_`?  that looks like a fortran symbol. do you have some fortran stuff floating around?

Comment: @Anycorn No, I don't, it is pure `C++11`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to `include <omp.h>` or to disable eigen's parallelization (for instance if your application is already parallelized with OpenMP).
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html